# When I click upload photo in Flutter WebView, I want to upload photo from phone

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

When I click on the photo upload input on the website in Flutter WebView, I want to select and upload a photo from the phone. I don't know how to solve this problem. Can you help?

The codes of the website are as follows:

```
<div class="foto-upload">
    <label class="foto-buton">
        <input type="file" name="resim" multiple="multiple" id="fileupload">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        <span>FOTOĞRAF EKLE</span>
        <b>YA DA SÜRÜKLE BIRAK</b>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="thumb_id" id="thumb_id" value="">
    <div class="foto-list">
        <div class="foto-count">EKLEDİĞİNİZ FOTOĞRAF ADEDİ: 
            <span id="mediaCount" data-total="0">0/10</span>
            <span id="mediaStatus"></span>
            <span id="filePercent"></span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Below are the Flutter/Dart codes:

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: '***',
  onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
     widget._controllerCompleter.future
           .then((value) => widget._controller = value);
     widget._controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
  },
  onPageStarted: (url) {
     setState(() {
        loadingPercentage = 0;
     });
  },
  onProgress: (progress) {
     setState(() {
        loadingPercentage = progress;
     });
  },
  onPageFinished: (url) {
     setState(() {
        loadingPercentage = 100;
     });
  },
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  javascriptChannels: _createJavascriptChannels(context),
),
```

Comment: Try to declare your `input` like: `<input id="photo" type="file" accept="image/*" capture</input>`

Comment: checkout stackoverflow.com/a/77155112/1979347 for fixing file upload issue on Android using webview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author) to handle file upload or to take photos/videos directly using something like `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`.

To be able to manage file upload, you need additional setup for Android and iOS. Check the [Enable camera for HTML inputs](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro#enable-camera-for-html-inputs) official docs online!

Here is an example using the current latest plugin version 6 ([6.0.0-beta.18](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.18)):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb &&
      kDebugMode &&
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(kDebugMode);
  }

  await Permission.camera.request();
  await Permission.microphone.request(); // if you need microphone permission

  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("InAppWebView test"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <label for="avatar">Choose photos:</label>
  <input type="file" name="resim" multiple="multiple" id="fileupload">
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="avatar">Take a photo:</label>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
</body>

</html>
                """),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

[image: Android example]